# Instagram story scraper: What would the process be?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, instagram

I'm trying to code a web scraping python program that gets stories from users with your login. I thought It would be fun to see if I could even get it working since the [4k Stogram](https://www.4kdownload.com/products/product-stogram) costs money just for more functionality.

I logged in successful but I don't know where to go from here.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json, random, re, requests, urllib.request
import urllib2

USERNAME = '*****'
PASSWD = '****'
account_purging = '****'

BASE_URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
LOGIN_URL = BASE_URL + 'ajax/'

headers_list = [
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; FSL 7.0.6.01001)",
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; FSL 7.0.7.01001)",
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; FSL 7.0.5.01003)",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; de; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100723 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.8",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; de; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100723 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.8",
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; .NET CLR 1.0.3705)",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)",
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)",
    "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.10.289 Version/12.01",
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.02",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1",
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0) Opera 7.02 Bork-edition [en]"
    ]

USER_AGENT = headers_list[random.randrange(0,(len(headers_list)+1))]

session = requests.Session()
session.headers = {'user-agent': USER_AGENT}
session.headers.update({'Referer': BASE_URL})
req = session.get(BASE_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
body = soup.find('body')

pattern = re.compile('window._sharedData')
script = body.find("script", text=pattern)

script = script.get_text().replace('window._sharedData = ', '')[:-1]
data = json.loads(script)

csrf = data['config'].get('csrf_token')
login_data = {'username': USERNAME, 'password': PASSWD}
session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': csrf})
login = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)

story_page = "https://www.instagram.com/stories" + "/" + account_purging

# stories url is:
request_headers_story = {
    "Accept:" : "video/webm,video/ogg,video/*;q…q=0.7,audio/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Language" : "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Connection" : "keep-alive",
    "DNT" : "1",
    "Host" : "scontent-ort2-1.cdninstagram.com",
    "Range" : "bytes=0-",
    "Referer" : story_page,
    "TE" : "Trailers",
    "User-Agent" : USER_AGENT
}

soup = session.post(story_page, data=request_headers_story, allow_redirects=True)
print(BeautifulSoup(soup.content, 'html.parser'))
```

I'm trying to get the mp4 and jpg links and using that to download later in an array or something. If there's anything you could point me towards I would appreciate anything.

I'm also trying to avoid using the api because, that just makes it boring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier solution to this problem which avoids using an api is to use selenium. By using selenium, you can login in much faster and efficiently as well as grab the images and videos you need.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
#or driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Note: To grab the image, you need to find the id or name of the image and do something like:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("image_id")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_name("image_name")
```

If you need more information or clarification, check https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/.

Let me know if that helped you!